# Isolated storage using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, windows-phone-8, ionic-framework

I am creating an windows app using angularjs and phonegap, which will run on windows 8 phones.

Here I want to store and retrieve images from isolated store.I have searched a lot for this but did not find any helpful information.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you seen EZ_iso yet? http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=2

Comment: @AMR: Thanks for links I going to this EZ_iso now... But will it support angular js ?

Comment: If you can execute .NET dlls from angular js, then I don't see why it wouldn't work.